# SQL Joining data when it is grouped and has different frequency

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, time-series, frequency

Currently, I have two tables. The data in both is of a time series nature but is in a flat format. In the first table, I currently have a dataset of dates, a company identifier and a value of interest. Both the company identifier and the value are numerical. Another thing to point out is that the companyid/date pairs are unique so there are no duplicates in the dataset. Below is an example of a couple of rows of the data in the first table.

```
companyid date        value1

1111      09/14/1986  1234
1111      10/14/1986  5678
1001      09/14/1986  5675
1001      10/10/1986  5930
```

The second table is similar since it also has companyid(s), dates, and several columns of values. What I would like to do is write a SQL query to join the two tables. More specifically, for every companyid I would like to add the value columns from the second table but only for those companyid/date pairs that exist in the first table. The first table has approximately 2m+ rows and the second table has approximately 25m+ rows.

Example of intended result
Table #1: See above
Table #2:

```
companyid date ... several value columns ...

1001      09/14/1986  4275  4447 ...
1001      10/10/1986  5924  7728 ...
1001      11/14/1986  3356  4822 ...
1001      12/14/1986  2539  2849 ...
1111      05/04/1993  2398  1209 ...
1111      09/14/1986  5945  4567 ...
1111      10/14/1986  2039  6797 ...
```

Merged Table:

```
companyid   date        value1 ... several value columns ...

1111        09/14/1986  1234  5945  4567 ...
1111        10/14/1986  5678  2039  6797 ...
1001        09/14/1986  5675  4275  4447 ...
1001        10/10/1986  5930  5924  7728 ...
```

Comment: Please show some sample data for both tables and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added sample data for both tables and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly. What you can do is

```
 Select t.companyid, t.date, t.value
     From table table t inner join 
           table1 t1 on t1.companyid = t.companyid 
                     and t.date =t1.date
```

Comment: A simple join on companyid and date will not work in this case.

Comment: @user6893 based on your question, this is exactly what you asked for.  Can you please revise your requirements?  Inner join provides the removal requirememts you specified, then just add the `t2` columns in your select.

Comment: @EvanL Updated requirements and simplified explanation.

Comment: +1 . . . even though the syntax is not quite correct, I think the inner join is the right logic.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of data.  And if you actually want to replace the data in the first table, then I would suggest using the truncate/re-insert method:

```
Select t1.companyid, t1.date, t2.value, t1.value1, t1.value2, . . .
into #temp
From table1 t1 inner join 
     table2 t2
     on t1.companyid = t2.companyid and
        t1.date = t2.date;

truncate table table1;

alter table table1 add value1 int;

insert into table1 (companyid, date, value, value1, value2, . . .)
    select companyid, date, value, value1, value2, . . .
    from #temp;
```

You could also put together a `merge` command, but the overhead of doing lots of deletes and inserts can be a lot.  Not to mention the overhead of adding a new integer column into a very full table.

I'm pretty sure the `inner join` does provide the data that you want.